# How to select tinyMCE textarea when pressing tab key?

Tags: tinymce, tabindex

Hello
I got similar to that code

```
<form method="post" action="/" name="form" autocomplete="off">
<input type="text" name="title" />
<textarea name="body"></textarea>
<input type="text" name="tags" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Where the "textarea" is tinyMCE... problem comes when I try to move selection through input and textarea items.
When the page is loaded it focus input[name=text] but when I press Tab key it select input[name=tags] instead textarea[name=body] (which is next)
Can you assist me with that issue ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is impossible with conventional tab indexes as TinyMCE actually hides the `<textarea>` and creates an `<iframe>` with the editor in it. You could make a work around by forcing focus on the editor in the blur event of the previous element in javascript, here is ajQuery snipped of the top of my head:

```
$('#prev-input').blur(function(){
    tinyMCE.get('textarea').focus();
});
```

Then as soon as the user leaves the previous input focus would jump to the TinyMCE editor, you could possibly add a blur() method as well to got to the next element.

Comment: That sounds good but returns error ---- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'focus' of undefined

Comment: You need to change `tinyMCE.get('textarea')` pending on your setup/init code.

Comment: I think it can't find the "textarea" because the tinyMCE object exists... I have try with the textarea's ID and NAME instead of "textarea" in get() but still wont work.

Comment: Is "setup/init" == "tiny_mce_init.js" or something else and what to look for in it ?

Comment: I did it with ---->  tinyMCE.activeEditor.focus();

Comment: Cool, glad you sorted it. Will keep note of activeEditor.

Comment: be aware that if you have several editors on one page activeEditor may refer to another editor (i.e. when you wrote text in editor nr 2, but then click a button in editor nr 1)

Comment: This code will not work in every case. If you have more than 2 elements to be focus. For Eg. If your sequence is 1-2-3. that means if you lost focus from 1 then go to 2 and then 3. but if you want to go directly form 1 to 3 and you tried to click on 3, then the focus will be set to 2 not to 3. I tried this and had faced the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

I resolved this with adding 'tabfocus' to plugins and then add tabfocus_elements : ":prev,:next"

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Plugin:tabfocus

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/tabfocus_elements

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work with set focus on `<label for="tinyMCE">`

Answer (score 3):

There is a plugin solved it

http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1657397&group_id=103281&atid=738747

I known it from TinyMCE forum

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=813

Answer (score 1):

I needed a custom tabbing order from another element on the page.  The code I used to resolve this in IE11 was

```
var button = $('#btn-id');
button.on('keydown', function (e) {
    if ((e.which === 9 && !e.shiftKey)) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(tinyMCE.get()[0].contentWindow).focus();
    }
});
```

Be aware that the above code will only work if you've only got one editor on the page.  Otherwise you'll have to cycle through the array returned by `tinyMCE.get()` to find the correct editor to set focus to.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the `focus` event is being triggered but focussing in the element (container) didn't work all the time.

In my case I tabbed from editor 1 - 4 and when I shift+tab I lost focus on the instance.

To fix this I added the following to the setup event of tinyMCE

```js
setup: function(editor) {
  editor.on("focus", function(e) {
    e.target.editorContainer.scrollIntoView();
  });
}
```